# MVVM Set Cursor in end of text in EditText when using afterTextChanged fuction

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, observable

my problem is when my edit text add comma cursor will move to first of text how to set the cursor always in the end of edit text when using ObservableField and mvvm this is my xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_amount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_amount"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="@={viewmodel.amount}"
    android:afterTextChanged="@{viewmodel.afterTextChanged}"/>
```

this is my view model

```
var amount = ObservableField<String>()
fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable){
    var longValue : Long
    var originalText = editable.toString()
    if(originalText.isNullOrEmpty())
        return

    longValue = originalText.convertCurrencyToLong()
    amount.set(longValue.convertToCurrency())
}
```

this is my helper

```
object CurrencyHelper{
   const val SIMPLE_CURRENCY_SPLIT = ","
   const val SIMPLE_CURRENCY_STRING = "#,###"

   @JvmField val SIMPLE_CURRENCY_FORMAT = object : ThreadLocal<NumberFormat>(){
       override fun initialValue(): NumberFormat {
           return DecimalFormat(SIMPLE_CURRENCY_STRING)
       }
   }
}

fun Long.convertToCurrency(): String = CurrencyHelper.SIMPLE_CURRENCY_FORMAT.get().format(this)

fun String.convertCurrencyToLong() : Long = this.replace(CurrencyHelper.SIMPLE_CURRENCY_SPLIT.toRegex(), "").toLong()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could a BindingAdapter for it

```
@BindingAdapter("cursorPosition")
@JvmStatic
fun setCursorPosition(editText: EditText, value: String?) {
    value ?: return
    editText.setSelection(value.length)
}
```

and in your layout use is as

```
cursorPosition="@{viewmodel.amount}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You're operating on an `Editable`. In this you can replace text as well. You don't need to reset the whole text of the `EditText`.

```
fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable){
    val oldText = editable.toString()
    if(oldText.isNullOrEmpty()) return
    val newText = originalText.convertCurrencyToLong().convertToCurrency()
    if (oldText == newText) return
    editable.replace(0, oldText.length, newText)
}
```

With this You should preserve the selection as well. If not you can set it with `Selection.setSelection(editable, start, end)` to the `Editable` directly.

Answer (score 0):

In general you change the position of the cursor of a EditText by using this method: `EditText#setSelection(int index)`, e.g.: `myEditText.setSelection(42)`. Be careful that the index is not longer than the actual text of the EditText.

Using MVVM and the data bindings framework makes it a bit trickier. Depending on your complete architecture you have two choices.

If you have a reference to the View (e.g. Activity, Fragment, ViewHolder, etc.) in your viewModel, then you can just call a method of the view and inside it you can set the position of the cursor as shown above.

If you do not have a reference to the view then you will have to use a binding adapter like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:afterTextChanged")
public static void setTextWatcher(EditText view, YourViewModel viewModel) {
  view.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
    ... other methods
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       viewModel.afterTextChanged(s);
       view.setSelection(s.length() - 1);
    }
  })
}
```

Note that you can bind any kind of object instead of the viewModel if you want or need. You can for example make an interface in order to not couple your ViewModel directly.